# Can Python async loop be async?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I saw at [concurrency is not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism) slide that golang can do like this:

```
func main() {
    go boring("Boring!")
    fmt.Println("I'm listening.")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("You're boring; I'm leaving.")
}
```

The result look like this

```
I'm listening.
boring 0
boring 1
boring 2
boring 3
boring 4
boring 5
You're boring; I'm leaving.
```

Can Python async loop do like this? I'm stuck it at `loop.run_forever` that it will block the main function:

```
import asyncio
import random
import time
import itertools


async def boring(msg):
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        print(msg, i)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() % 1e3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(boring('boring!'))
    loop.run_forever()
    print('Hello')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Bye.')
    loop.stop()
```

It will then run

```
boring! 0
boring! 1
boring! 2
boring! 3
boring! 4
boring! 5
boring! 6
boring! 7
boring! 8
boring! 9
```

Can python async loop be async?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleeping after running run_until_complete, you can use [timeouts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts). This way, it would be something like:

```
async def main():
    print('Hello')
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(boring('boring!'), timeout=2.0)
        print('Maybe not that boring!')
    except:
        print('Bye.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This will also automatically cancel the running task when the timeout happens. If you don't want the task to be canceled after timeout, use `wait` instead of `wait_for`.

Answer (score 0):

`loop.run_forever()` if blocking the execution. As your code is running in a single thread, you need to modify your code to something like this:

```
async def boring(msg):
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        print(msg, i)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() % 1e3)

async def hello(task):
    print('Hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('Bye.')
    task.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = asyncio.ensure_future(boring('boring!'))
    loop.run_until_complete(hello(t))
    loop.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm stuck on the last piece about async in Python. If I want to use async in Python, did that mean I will end up my program with a loop.run_until_complete()?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean. To execute asynchronous functions you need a `run_until_complete` or `run_forever` call that will block the thread for the time being then continue the normal process.

Comment: At one point, you have to give up control of a thread to the `EventLoop` so that it can manage the async stuff. You can think of `loop.run_until_complete()` and `loop.run_forever()` as transition between synchronous land and async land.